# Flickering images while spinning

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: grey;
            }
            img.Billgates {
                margin-top: 30px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                display:block;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
                -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
                animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
            }
                @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
                @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
                @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function billFunction(img) {
        var Bill = document.getElementById('BillGate');
        if (img.src.match("Bill")) {
            img.src = "images/bill-gates.jpg";
        } else {
            img.src = "images/Card.jpg";
        }
    }
    function outbillFunction(img) {
    var Out = document.getElementById('BillGate');
    if (img.src.match("Bill")) {
        img.src="images/Card.jpg";
    }
    else {
        img.src = "images/bill-gates.jpg";
    }
    }
    /* End of JavaScript code */
        </script>
        <img id="BillGate" src="images/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Bill Gates" class="Billgates" onmouseover="billFunction(this)" onmouseout="outbillFunction(this)"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello! This is my code and im wondering how i can change image every second without hovering over it, so it basically spins around but changes image every second. I want the pictures to be images/bill-gates.jpg and images/Card.jpg Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to look at the setInterval method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the function call from onmouseover and out add the following code.

window.setInterval(function()
{

/// call your function here

}, 1000);

Comment: How do i set a function that changes the image was my question as well :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove both of the Mouse Overs, and implement the setInterval method

However;

Make sure you can default pack to the original, as you have two functions originally, I'd personally go for modifying your two existing function into one bigger one so when you call the function in the method setInterval, your function checks for both cases and replaces accordingly.

I hope this helps a little.